# How to add an autocomplete dropdown to an existing element on a default lightning record page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

(Apologies in advance for the vague question)

We have an existing js widget for autocompleting addresses in webpages that shows autocomplete suggestions in a dropdown while a user is typing the address.

We managed to get this connecting to standard record address fields in default Lightning pages with v39 Lightning with a component/app wrapper (to make it slightly more native and work around API callback issues from the CRM framework)

However, with the new LockerService in v40, this prevents accessing the DOM outside our component via standard JS (e.g. `document.querySelector(element.className)`) and thus preventing us from locating existing address fields in the DOM.

So, my question is two-fold:

1. In v40, *is there a way to traverse the DOM of a component* that is on the same page as your component? We do not necessarily need to alter the DOM only listen & populate values. (Presumably not, as this seems to be the point of LockerService)
2. If not, *is there a way to extend the standard* `Record Detail` *component* that is used in the default record pages? (So that the user can replace the standard `Record Detail` component with our enhanced one?)

Comment: 1. I don't know. 2. you can create your own component to display record details and replace it with the standard one in the appbuilder. Or, if you want to add your code to the bottom of the detail component - create a visualforce page and add it to the standard layout.

Comment: 1) No - LockerService will prevent you from doing (for a good reason). You'd have to write your own component to handle the address input which fires an application event that your map component can listen to.

Comment: @ItaiShmida could the `Record Detail` component be generic, the same way the standard one is? Do you know of any info re how to do this?

Comment: this is not a simple task, but possible. it should be something like a fieldSet functionality. for view only it is simple, for editable - much more complicated. I am working not on something similar (from a modal) it is not 100% dynamic, and not yet done